# RxJava subscribe to blocking observable

Tags: rx-java

I'd like to achieve the following:

```
String result = myObservable.toBlocking().first();
```

i.e. it is like a regular function call. However this never happens because you'd need to subscribe to it, which I don't know how to do. If I subscribe to it, the result will be in another scope, and the code is very ugly because I can only get the result like its a regular observable anyway, so there's no point turning it into a blocking observable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It actually works as you want:

```
    Observable<String> myObservable = Observable.just("firstValue", "secondValue");
    String result = myObservable.toBlocking().first();
    System.out.println(result); // ---> "firstValue"
```

Under the hood, calling `BlockingObservable.first()` does the subscription for you:

```
private T blockForSingle(final Observable<? extends T> observable) {
    final AtomicReference<T> returnItem = new AtomicReference<T>();
    final AtomicReference<Throwable> returnException = new AtomicReference<Throwable>();
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Subscription subscription = ((Observable<T>)observable).subscribe(new Subscriber<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            latch.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(final Throwable e) {
            returnException.set(e);
            latch.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(final T item) {
            returnItem.set(item);
        }
    });
    BlockingUtils.awaitForComplete(latch, subscription);

    if (returnException.get() != null) {
        Exceptions.propagate(returnException.get());
    }

    return returnItem.get();
}
```

**UPDATE**: If doesn't make any sense to use a `BehaviourSubject` plus `toBlocking()`. Have into account that it is both and `Observable` and an `Observer` so somewhere, `myObservable.onNext("value")` should be invoked. If you block the thread by calling `toBlocking()`, unless `myObservable` is available in some other thread where `onNext()` is called, you are gonna get blocked.

For instance, this is the normal use of a `BehaviourSubject:

```
  // observer will receive the "one", "two" and "three" events, but not "zero"
  BehaviorSubject<Object> subject = BehaviorSubject.create("default");
  subject.onNext("zero");
  subject.onNext("one");
  subject.subscribe(observer);
  subject.onNext("two");
  subject.onNext("three");
```

Comment: Interesting, I forget that this is a BehaviorSubject actually.. Does making that make a difference? it blocks the whole thread for me indefinitely.